# How to find fields with mapping conflicts

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4

My index settings in Kibana tell me that I have fields with mapping conflicts in my logstash-* index patterns.

What is the easiest way to find out which fields have a conflicting mapping and/or in which indices the conflict occurs?

Comment: @AndreiStefan That's the thing it just says that there is a mapping conflict. It doesn't show me where it is...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of at least Kibana 5.2, you can type "conflict" into the Filter field, which will filter all fields down to only those which have a conflict. At the far right there is a column named "controls", and for each field it has a button with a pencil icon. Clicking that will tell you which indices have which mapping.

Fields filtered to only those with conflicts:
[image: fields filtered to only those with conflicts]

Indices in which field mapping conflicts:
[image: indices in which field mapping conflicts]

Comment: Is it possible that kibana 6.4 doesn't have this "controls" column? Was it removed in later versions?

Comment: @deez 6.4.0 does have the `controls` column, but the panel it leads to doesn't show the indices any more - just lets you edit how Kibana views the field.

Comment: Same for 6.6.0: no index list anymore

Answer (score 7):

You can easily find how fields are mapped using the mapping API in Kibana.

If you know you have a mapping conflict, I will assume you know the field name that has the conflict.  These will be listed under Management/Index Patterns/index_pattern

If you have indices that are created daily, such as production-2020.06.16, you can search across all the indices with production*.

Go to Dev Tools and enter this query, changing the index pattern (production*) and conflictedFieldname to suit your needs.

```
GET production*/_mapping/field/conflictedFieldname
```

This will pull all indices that match the production* pattern and will list the mapping for conflictedFieldname for each index.  Scroll through and see which one is not like the other one.

You can also check out the Elasticsearch documentation here: [Elasticsearch documentation: Get Field Mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-field-mapping.html)

The reason you're getting a conflict is because the first value that goes into the index is used by Elasticsearch to make its best guess as to what data type it should be.  You can ensure it is always the same type by placing a template for the index pattern you are concerned with.

[Elasticsearch documentation: Put Index Template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html)

Comment: "I will assume you know the field name that has the conflict" - No the question is specifically HOW to find those field names.

Answer (score 4):

In Elasticsearch 5.5.2, you can click on the dropdown on the right of the Filter search box and select "conflict". This is in the Index Patterns page.

Comment: This also works in recent versions (e.g. 6.5.0) of elastic

Answer (score 1):

It should be easy to spot those in the list of fields, when defining the pattern. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: my Problem is that the field marker does not show up for whatever reason.

Comment: And if you sort that column?

Comment: for whatever reason it does not show up. Even though it used when I had a similar problem some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't locate the mapping conflict in the gui. I went down the hard path analysed my config for missing/conflicting field type found the offender and reindexed my data.

Comment: How exactly did you do this, could you, please, point some details

Comment: @MaximGalushka I basically went through my last couple of changes and checked wether I specified the correct typecasts in my logstash grok filters...

Comment: I see, unfortunately in our system types are assigned automatically as well as new fields are added, so we need to analyze existing indexes and understand type issues from them

Answer (score 0):

If you click the type column on the index patterns page where the warning is displayed, it should sort the indexes by type. Conflicted fields will have type 'conflict'.